# query execution

Tags: sql-server-2008

1)

```
declare @OrderBy varchar(100) = 'CompanyName'
declare @SortingOrder varchar(5) = 'desc'

Select * from [User] order by (@OrderBy + '  ' + @SortingOrder)
```

2)

```
Select * from [User] order by CompanyName desc
```

If I use the 2nd query then the result comes true (as I expected), but if I use the 1st query then result is not as expected.

I mean that the result set is displayed by ordering the company name in descending order.

What is the wrong in 1st query?
Someone please explain this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For query number 1, you can't specify the column you want to order by dynamically the way you're trying to do it.  You could however build a sql string and execute it using EXEC:

```
declare @OrderBy varchar(100) = 'CompanyName'
declare @SortingOrder varchar(5) = 'desc'
declare @sql varchar(1000)
SET @sql = 'Select * from [User] order by ' + @OrderBy + ' ' + @SortingOrder
EXEC(@sql)
```

Or if you want to avoid dynamic SQL, you can use a CASE WHEN statement in your ORDER BY:

```
declare @OrderBy varchar(100) = 'CompanyName'
declare @so varchar(5) = 'desc'

SELECT * FROM [User] 
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'CompanyName' AND @so = 'desc' THEN CompanyName END DESC,
  CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'CompanyName' AND @so <> 'desc' THEN CompanyName END
```

Comment: If you even think about using dynamic SQL, you **MUST** read [The curse and blessing of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) !

Comment: @marc_s Good link, thanks. And, sorry, it's late over here and I completely forgot you could use CASE WHEN in the ORDER BY, which in most cases I prefer to dynamic SQL.